# Php bitcount implemantation errors

Tags: php

Suppose you have two binary values:

```
001011 and 001111
```

How can you get the number of different bits in MySQL? I tried:

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT(BINARY  001011 ^ BINARY 001111)
```

This returns 6.I mean how to implement it?
I means either i need from fetching mysql query or from php script?Please help.

Comment: Is your desired output 1, in this case?

Comment: Yes ofcourse,but how to implement it???Please help.

Comment: Yup it is same but not what i asking???

Comment: then can you explain it more?

Comment: ok,for example you have two no. 95750 and 74898.We have to count different bits in this,function for that is SELECT BIT_COUNT(BINARY  74898 ^ BINARY 95750).Now how to implement it.I short suppose bitcount no. of above query is 6.Then it is not dsiplaying 6.

Comment: Is your requirement is to display the value in your page?

Comment: Yes my dear,that is what i want..

Comment: Is this PHP, or is it MySQL?

Comment: I is Mysql query,if you are having extra solution please provide.@http://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww

Answer (score 0):

perform sql operation with query

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT(BINARY  001011 ^ BINARY 001111) as bitcount
```

then print the result,say `$result['bitcount']`

Comment: It says 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'BIT_COUNT' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\script.php on line 4.But never mind,i have found a alternate solution for this.Thanx.

Comment: Good to hear that:) Please put the solution here, so that it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score -1):

Answer is [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

```
$bit = "001011";
$count = strlen($bit);
echo $count;
```

**OUTPUT :** 6

**[Demo](https://eval.in/181949)**

Comment: It is ok,but how to compare both as 001011 ^ BINARY 001111 of different bit in both???